# Async function with package:js in dart

Tags: javascript, dart, google-chrome-extension

so I need to write this JS fragment:

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(async function fetchJson(clickData){
    if(clickData.menuItemId == "selectedText" && clickData.selectionText){
        register(clickData.selectionText);
    }
})
```

with package:js in Dart. I can do the listener, but I am having issue with declaring an async funtion fetchJson. Could someone show me how to create that using a @JS header?
I only know how to create simple functions like this:

```
@JS('chrome.contextMenus.create()')
external void createContext(not_sure_what_type here);
```